# Magento1.9 - AWS SES not working with Magento1.9 SMTP extension

Tags: magento-1.9, smtp, amazonses

I'm getting the below error message while sending an email using Amazon SES in Magento1.9.2.4(Aschroder SMTPPro extension).

I'm using the same credentials in Magento2.3(Mageplaza SMTP extension) which are working.

I think the below code is used to get authentication key:

```
<?php
private function _buildAuthKey($date){
    return sprintf('AWS3-HTTPS AWSAccessKeyId=%s,Algorithm=HmacSHA256,Signature=%s', $this->_accessKey, base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $date, $this->_privateKey, TRUE)));
}
?>
```

Thank you.